# How to add files to .plist in xcode iphone project?

Tags: iphone, ios, plist, text-files

I have a `txt` file with values(All english words) and am parsing the values from txt file in my code. But, it takes a long time to parse. I want to add the the values with keys in plist. I don't know how to add files in `plist file`. Can anyone please guide me to add files into plist? I searched about this in Google and i got some ideas to parse the file from plist but not get the solution to add files to plist. Now am having the values in txt file like this,

```
Apple
Samsung
Nokia
Motorola
LG
Sony
iPhone
HTC
iPad
Mac
```

I just imported this txt file in my xcode and parsed the txt file in a class.
Now, i asked to use this txt file as property list. How can i do this? Please help me. I don't have any more ideas on this.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think a property list would take longer to parse than a text file.

Comment: @icktoofay thanks for your response. But, i want to set the txt file with key and value pair in property list. Can you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Is this a dynamic file (does it grow or shrink in content)? How many key/value pairs are you talking about? Can you give more details on what the parsing involves? There might be a straightforward answer if you can provide a few more details.

Comment: @Jim Thanks for your response. I have edited my question. I want to transfer the txt file details into property list. Can you please help me. I dont know how to add the property list in xcode. Please clarify my silly doubts. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Steps to add plist in Xcode4.2 iPhone project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044735/steps-to-add-plist-in-xcode4-2-iphone-project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read this question and answer. You can get some ideas.

[Steps to create and edit a plist file in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044735/steps-to-add-plist-in-xcode4-2-iphone-project)

Thanks.