# Steps to create and edit a plist file in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, plist, key-value

I want to add key pair values in `plist`. I dont know how to add the .plist file in XCode. Simply i want to add these details in .plist file named as "`Mobile.plist`".

```
Apple - iPhone,iPod,iPad
Samsung - Galaxy Y, Galaxy R, Galaxy Z
Nokia - Lumina
LG - Lg1 ,Lg2, Lg3
```

I have tried the steps to create a new Mobile.plist file by using this link,

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-create-an-iphone-preferences-file. But, i cant get it exactly. When i tried to use the steps from this link, the plist file always empty. I don't know how to add the key, values in plist.

I have created one group named as `Settings and add new plist file named as Root.plist`. Can you please provide the steps to create .plist file and add key,values in it.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Right click on the folder you want to add it to and choose "New file…"

From the Dialog - create a new Resource file of type Property List:

[image]

Give it whatever name you want, the plist extension will be added for you. In this case I've created Root.plist

This will bring up a blank file with columns for Key, Type and Value.

[image]

Right click in the file and choose "Add Row"

[image]

Choose any of the presented options, you'll be overwriting it anyway.

[image]

Now change the Key to "Apple". Right click in the type section, where it currently says String and change it to Array.

[image]

Click on the disclosure triangle next to where it says Apple so it faces downwards and then right click in the row and choose "Add Row" This will create a subrow under the Apple key. Repeat this until you have three rows:

[image]

Edit the values to the three items that you want

[image]

Click on the Disclosure triangle to the left of "Apple" on the top row so it points to the right. Right click on the row and choose "Add Row". This will create a new top level item.

[image]

Since you have four top level items, each which contains an array, repeat the above process so that you get the structure you want.

[image]

If you want to see the raw plist file, right click on the plist file in the project navigator and choose "Open As | Source Code"

[image]

And you'll see the raw file

[image]

And to get back to the editor view: right click on the file again and choose "Open As | Property List"

[image]

Comment: Great answer, can this be modified during the build process, like config transforms in Visual Studio?

Comment: please update code to access these plist items in swift

Answer (score 1):

A little update for the newer XCode versions

1. Right click on the folder you want the file -> `New File...`
2. Search for `property` and choose Property List
3. Name it whatever you want, e.g. "Products"

[image]