# How to create Entitlement.plist file in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, entitlements

I have downloaded the latest version of Xcode. I want to create Entitlement.plist file in my project.

Please give me proper steps to create an `Entitlement.plist` file in Xcode.

Comment: for this already has an answer [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044735/steps-to-create-and-edit-a-plist-file-in-xcode)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can manage the Entitlements in the *Capabilities* tab of your target settings.

Any change there will automatically update either the `Entitlements.plist` or the `Info.plist` file.

That being said, an `Entitlements.plist` file is in the end just a `plist`. You can add as much `plist`s as you like following the steps provided [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044735/steps-to-create-and-edit-a-plist-file-in-xcode).

Comment: But I want add a new Entitlement.plist
There is no option in Capabilities  to add a new Entitlement.plist

Comment: Thanks for your answer I am working on this , Will let you know if that helped.

Comment: I still have the problem happening.  It only happens when my app is re-opened via a Deeplink with the following app delegate method: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url      If I just start the app, keychain writing works, and if I minimize and maximize the app, it still works.   It's only when I re-open with the deep link that this problem occurs.    I do have MyApp.entitlements configured in my project ( Keychain Sharing in the Capabilities tab).

Comment: I think it's not work under iOS16 (beta3) and Xcode Version 14.0 beta 3 (14A5270f), I want to add "com.apple.developer.device-information.user-assigned-device-name" and show device name, it's still not work.

Comment: It's work under "apple enterprise account program" ?

Comment: @Uthen, have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 24):

In Xcode 5, for common entitlements you no longer need to create an `Entitlements.plist` file manually. You use the new Capabilities pane instead. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html

If you still want to create one manually, here's how:

1. File menu > New File...
2. Select iOS > Resource > Property List
3. Name the new file "`foo.entitlements`" (typically, "`foo`" is the target name)
4. Click the (+) next to "Entitlements File" to add a top-level item (the property list editor will use the correct schema due to the file extension)

Don't forget to set your target's `CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS` build setting to be the path to entitlements file you just added.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to add an Entitlement to an existing project in Xcode 5 follow these steps:

1. Select your project in the Navigator area.
2. Select your Target in the Editor area.
3. In the Editor area select the Capabilities option from the menu bar.
4. Open the disclosure button to the left of the Keychain Sharing option.
5. Under Keychain Sharing select the "+" button.
6. Type the entitlement in the input area.
7. DONE.

Comment: Simplest answer. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Thanks!!!! After much and much and much searching, this helped! For noobs like me, the disclosure button was a + button next to the word capabilities.

Answer (score 9):

You can manually create an `Entitlements.plist` file using the template below.

Save it as `YourTargetName.entitlements`

In your `Target > Build Settings`, set the key "Code Signing Entitlements" (`CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS`) to the file's path.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
    <key>beta-reports-active</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: are `$(AppIdentifierPrefix)` and `$(CFBundleIdentifier)` placeholders which one has to replace or are they replaced when the entitlement is parsed by `codesign`?

Comment: @EugenMayer I believe they will be replaced and you can leave them as is. But I'm not positive from when I posted this answer.

Comment: Actually the hole String line is no langer needed and will fail if included, just tried ist today

Answer (score -2):

CMD + SHIFT + K

to clean the build and rebuild by CMD + B worked for me