# iOS 8.1.3 - Enterprise Distribution - Application is missing the application-identifier entitlement

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, enterprise-distribution

I'm having so much problems with Enterpsie Distribution on iOS 8.1.3.
I managed to fix MOST of my installations which were giving this error:

```
Ignore manifest download, already have bundleID
```

with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25948839/517688

Which basically tells you to fake the bundleID on the server manifest.plist.

But on some of my test devices I'm getting a new error after the change:

```
Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=63 "Application is missing the application-identifier entitlement."
```

And I can't seem to find a solution for this one.

**EDIT 1**

I tried adding this to the .entitlements file:

```
<key>application-identifier</key>
<string>com.domain.appname</string>
```

but now I'm getting this error when trying to Archive the app for distribution:

```
None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: application-identifier, aps-environment.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The application-identifier entitlement is not formatted correctly;

It should contain your 10-character App ID Seed, followed by a dot, followed by your bundle identifier:

```
XXXXXXXXXX.com.domain.appname
```

Comment: where should I put this info? I can't find a .entitlements file, and I'm stuck.

Comment: Please follow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674514/how-to-create-entitlement-plist-file-in-xcode-5

Answer (score 8):

I have resolved this issue by following the steps from this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28235443/2638825

**For apps that have been signed by a third party** that you're resigning with your enterprise certificate (this walkthrough is assuming the ipa file is AcmeApp.ipa, your entitlements file is entitlements.plist and your provisioning profile is provProvile.mobileprovision; all files are in the Desktop folder (Mac OSX), and S836XXACME is your team identifier):

Create a new entitlements.plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>application-identifier</key>
<string>S836XXACME.uk.co.acme.AcmeApp</string>
<key>get-task-allow</key>
<false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Unzip the ipa:

```
cd ~/Desktop

unzip AcmeApp.ipa
```

Remove the Code Signature:

```
rm -r Payload/AcmeApp.app/_CodeSignature/
```

Copy in the mobileprovision file:

```
cp provProfile.mobileprovision Payload/AcmeApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision
```

Codesign:

```
codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: ACME Corporation Limited" --entitlements entitlements.plist Payload/AcmeApp.app
```

Zip it up as the resigned ipa:

```
zip -qr AcmeApp_resigned.ipa Payload/
```

You also need to amend the manifest.plist file as per the 'ALREADY' signed part earlier:

```
<key>bundle-identifier</key>
<string>S836XXACME.uk.co.acme.AcmeApp</string>
```

I tried this solution on iOS 8.4.1, 8.4, 8.0.2 and 7.1.1 devices and it works for me.

thank you "Mark Chamberlain" :)

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused by Apple's security patch for 8.1.3. You could see the discussion from [Apple Developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1096945#1096945).

bllakjakk's answer is right. But just to make it clear, the 10-character App ID Seed is called Team ID and you could find it from your Organization Profile in Member Centre.

Comment: But how do you add it?

Answer (score 0):

As per the Technical Notes by Apple

> (your_app) failed to install
>   Unable to download application, (your_app) could not be downloaded at this time.
>   Application is missing the application-identifier entitlement
>   Upgrade's application-identifier entitlement string ({Your New App ID Prefix}.com,YourApp.Bundle.ID) does not match installed application's application-identifier string (({Your Old App ID Prefix}.YourApp.Bundle.ID); rejecting upgrade.

[Installation Failure Errors](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2407/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014991-CH1-INSTALLATION_FAILURE_ERRORS-APPLICATION_IS_MISSING_THE_APPLICATION_IDENTIFIER_ENTITLEMENT)

So you need to conform to this.