# Xcode App Store Submission Error: Application Identifier Entitlement Missing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uniqueidentifier

Upon submitting the binary to App Store, I get the following errors:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Notes**:

- Submission is with Xcode 11
- Project Created with Xcode 11
- Provisioning Profiles are newly made
- iOS app, Today Widget, Watch Extension, Watch App included
- Today Extension is using app gro

**Things I tried**:

- Cleaning build folder
- Cleaning Derived Data folder
- Reinstalling Xcode 11
- Cleaning Provisioning Profiles folder and redownloading profiles
- This is an App Store distributed app
- No 3rd party signing involved

### UPDATE

- I only have entitlement files on the main target and on Today Extension.  On others, there aren't any.
- App entitlement error is coming up on all targets, given above.
- App ID format is xxxxxx.com.companyname.app
- Bundle Identifiers have not been changed since the last update.
- All these have worked before, a few weeks prior to the last app update.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS 8.1.3 - Enterprise Distribution - Application is missing the application-identifier entitlement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371652/ios-8-1-3-enterprise-distribution-application-is-missing-the-application-ide)

Comment: @ElTomato, actually I came across that threat earlier and did not have luck with it.

Comment: Well, you didn’t say you tried removing / adding entitlements to get the entitlements file to rejigger itself. That’s what I usually do in these situations.

Comment: Have you read the following topic?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677133/app-installation-failed-due-to-application-identifier-entitlement

Comment: @matt could you elaborate on adding/removing entitlements?  Where is this done?

Comment: Try removing and adding entitlements again

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger entitlements to...?

Comment: Also I have another idea. Apple announced at WWDC that you have to stop using wildcard bundle identifiers. So maybe you need to regenerate your app ID info.

Comment: @matt I am using com.mycompany.app format

Comment: It’s not about what you’re using, it’s how the provisioning profile is constructed. You’ll notice that it’s the profile that is being criticized.

Comment: @matt Indeed. I am checking on the profile and App ID.  Not sure what to change...

Answer (score 0):

After hustling with it for hours straight, it because apparent that it's an XCode 11 issue. The way it is archiving.

Even though this is not the most practical solution, it worked for me:

1. Upgraded macOS to Bug Sur Beta
2. Installed Xcode 12 Beta alongside Xcode 11
3. Archived using Xcode 11
4. Submitted using Xcode 12

Just relieved I got the update submitted!