# macOS - Not authorized to send Apple Events to <>

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-mojave, info-plist

I'm using AppleScript (inside of a macOS app) to get the currently active tab name in a browser. The code is following:

```
"tell application \"Google Chrome\" to return title of active tab of front window"
```

Until recently, everything was working fine. However, when I switched to the new version of Catalina, I started getting the following errors:

```
skipped scripting addition "/Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax" because it is not SIP-protected.

{
    NSAppleScriptErrorAppName = "Google Chrome";
    NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage = "Not authorized to send Apple events to Google Chrome.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorMessage = "Not authorized to send Apple events to Google Chrome.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-1743";
    NSAppleScriptErrorRange = "NSRange: {43, 3}";
}
```

I've tried adding `NSAppleEventsUsageDescription` and setting its value, but that produced **no** changes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you calling this AppleScript from within an application, or are you running this as a stand-alone script (from the Script Editor, or an AppleScript app)?

Comment: In the application @TedWrigley

Comment: You're running into a Sandbox issue. In order for a sandboxed application to use applescripts you have to give it proper entitlements, setting the `NSAppleEventsUsageDescription` entitlement and either the `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events` entitlement or the `com.apple.security.scripting-targets` entitlement. This blog post gives a decent explanation: https://www.jessesquires.com/blog/executing-applescript-in-mac-app-on-macos-mojave/

Comment: @TedWrigley I did both. Nothing helped.

Comment: This was the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674514/how-to-create-entitlement-plist-file-in-xcode-5

Comment: @DragosStrugar Do you solved your problem? I am running into the same situation with Chrome in my sandboxed app.