# How to get an iPad's device name on iOS16?

Tags: ios, swift, wwdc, ios16, xcode14

UIDevice.current.name it's worked if used iOS15, but when I tested on iOS16 (beta3)
still return 'iPad' name all the time.

See related WWDC 2022 video file

1. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10096/
2. https://developers.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10068/

I used:

- iPadOS (iOS16 beta3)
- Xcode (Version 14.0 beta 3 (14A5270f))

I added on entitlement, but it's don't work
[image]

Comment: Why does anyone needs to `see related WWDC 2022 video file`? Is there any specific info there which you wanted to emphasise?

Comment: reviews on first video file (track: 0:03:11 - 0:03:50)  on "UIDevice.name requires the entitlement com.apple.developer.device-information.user-assigned-device-name"

Comment: and reviews on second video file (track 0:23:03)

Comment: So have you added that entitlement?

Comment: I guess the actual question you want to ask here: _How do I get that entitlement_, right? Well, [Apple hasn't told us yet](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708275)! So please file a Feedback with Apple.

Comment: yes, try to added entitlement file, but still don't work, when I debug device name still show 'iPad'

Comment: That's not how you add an entitlement. You need to [modify your `Entitlements.plist`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674514/how-to-create-entitlement-plist-file-in-xcode).

Comment: Thank you, I added an entitlement file, but don't have any information on dropdown list for about device name.

Comment: Please any new information about this entitlements

Comment: On iOS16 beta 4 : apple updated some document file : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_device-information_user-assigned-device-name

Comment: @Uthen do you fixed this problem if yes please can you share that

Comment: We can't fix the problem under Apple enterprise account program, we send request to apple team reviews and wait feedback.

Comment: Now it's worked apple approved i can access to User Assigned Device Name Entitlement web site (under apple enterprise account).  Contact to apple team and they will be help you. @HichemRomdhane

Comment: Now it's fixed >> step 1) approve from apple 2) change certificate to support on this feature 3) add file entitlements on iOS project.

Comment: revision from @uthen

Answer (score 8):

revision on what @uthen mentions

You should

- The account owner must fill up the request on User-Device [User-Device](https://developer.apple.com/contact/request/user-assigned-device-name/)
- Enable the "**additional capabilities**" in Developer Portal > IDentifiers > {App Id} > additional capabilities
- Generate new **provisioning profile** for development and AppStore
- if you don't have it "add a new file" property list, rename the file extension to `.entitlements` set the environment in the Build Settings `CODE SIGNING ENTITLEMENTS` top the path where the `[name].entitlements` file is located.
- in the entitlements file add a new empty entry and set the key to `com.apple.developer.device-information.user-assigned-device-name`, the type to `Boolean` and the value to `true`