# Ad Hoc iOS .ipa file won't install for devices

Tags: ios, xcode5, provisioning-profile, adhoc

I developed an application, archive it, and when I`m trying to instal it on my device, there are sone errors.
I have been over and over the certificates, devices and provisioning profiles in the iOS Dev Center. I've triple checked all the Build Settings in XCode. It is built in XCode 5.

When attempting to install the app on a device, this is the output from the console:

```
Nov  3 16:29:37 iPhone-4S itunesstored[96] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder LSApplicationProxy: Lezgro.MyCity (Placeholder)
Nov  3 16:29:37 iPhone-4S itunesstored[96] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:LSApplicationProxy: Lezgro.MyCity (Placeholder) withPhase:1
Nov  3 16:29:37 iPhone-4S lsd[991] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installState for parent <NSProgress: phase=Installing; state=Failed; fractionCompleted=0.740000> to LSInstallStateWaiting
Nov  3 16:29:37 iPhone-4S lsd[991] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: phase=Installing; state=Waiting; fractionCompleted=0.740000> to 1
Nov  3 16:29:37 iPhone-4S installd[62] <Notice>: 0x255000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-8408645959906944348/-1707336500984960283" requested by itunesstored
Nov  3 16:29:40 iPhone-4S touchsetupd[117] <Warning>: WPTransfer deallocing
Nov  3 16:29:40 iPhone-4S cplogd[1751] <Warning>: Starting.
Nov  3 16:29:41 iPhone-4S installd[62] <Notice>: 0x255000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app Lezgro.MyCity
Nov  3 16:29:41 iPhone-4S installd[62] <Error>: unrecognized status -67068 from codesigning library
Nov  3 16:29:41 iPhone-4S installd[62] <Error>: 0x255000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.xzbEO9/foo_extracted/Payload/MyCity.app/MyCity: 0xe8008001
Nov  3 16:29:41 iPhone-4S installd[62] <Error>: 0x255000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.xzbEO9/foo_extracted/Payload/MyCity.app
Nov  3 16:29:41 iPhone-4S installd[62] <Error>: 0x255000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
Nov  3 16:29:41 iPhone-4S itunesstored[96] <Error>: 0x1e7a000 MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices: failed with -1
Nov  3 16:29:41 iPhone-4S itunesstored[96] <Warning>: ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
Nov  3 16:29:41 iPhone-4S lsd[991] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation failed for app Lezgro.MyCity
Nov  3 16:29:41 iPhone-4S itunesstored[96] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: Lezgro.MyCity.Installing - <NSProgress: phase=Installing; state=Failed; fractionCompleted=0.000000> called, removing progress from cache
Nov  3 16:29:41 iPhone-4S installd[62] <Error>: 0x255000 handle_install_for_ls: API failed
Nov  3 16:29:43 iPhone-4S SpringBoard[34] <Warning>: Killing Lezgro.MyCity for app installation
```

I've tried absolutely everything I can think of. Any help, even ideas about how to diagnose the problem, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before.
Set the get-task-allow in Entitlement.plist to false. If your app does not include Entitlement.plist, you have to permit it on the target summary view.

Good luck!

Comment: is this solution for xcode 5? I don`t see Entitlements.plist file in project, but when I try to do like [here](http://esfandiarmaghsoudi.blogspot.com/2011/01/setting-up-entitlementsplist-file-in.html), its resurns error:CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.0'

Comment: You can add your Entitlement.plist like here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044735/steps-to-create-and-edit-a-plist-file-in-xcode

And than you can managed Entitlements in the Capabilities tab of your target settings.