# Can't add row in plist file xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5, plist

I need a help... Probably will be a silly question but a little bit new to objetive-c. The problem is:

1. I am trying to add a row in the key value but it doesn't work.
2. When I created the file at the begging didn't have any trouble but when I wrote "root" I couldn't add a row because I wanted to create a second key with all string in it.
3. I tried to cancel the entire file and redo a entire project and when I am going to create a new plist file it gives me back the same key of the project I had canceled.

I followed [this](http://www.appcoda.com/enhance-your-simple-table-app-with-property-list/) tutorial to do so but can't understand the trouble I have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Steps to create and edit a plist file in Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044735/steps-to-create-and-edit-a-plist-file-in-xcode)

Comment: Unfortunatly is not the answer that I was looking for...anyeay probably I found the way...now I try then I will post what I did... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new Property List, the created file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict/>
</plist>
```

When you open this file within Xcode's designated editor, it shows you an empty document with a "Root" Dictionary. It's a smart editor :) and it all starts with that "Root".

Comment: Ahn ok...so you mean that I leave it as I see with type: (Dictionary) and add a row as a new "Item" and put all the things I need?...Is correct? Thanks for the answer : ) ...

Comment: Yes. Add an item & select the type (string or dictionary or whatever) and fill in the data.

Comment: Thanks @user1804762 your answer helped me a lot :-)